# Combine 2 variables from a 8 variables set, with the difference from each row

Tags: r, ggplot2, finance, stock

**Hi,** and thanks for all help. I have a dataset with 8 variables and 5 observations. What i want to do is to take 2 variables from the dataset with every 5 observations. In these variables and have digits such as high.price and low.price from five different days hence the observations. What i want is to take the variables *High.price* and *Low.price* into a new dataset and plot a genom_line with the difference between the *high.price* and *low.price* such as the difference to be **"y"** on the plot and **"x"** as date the 5 observations.

What i want is that i want to calculate the difference between High.price and Low.price for each five days, and then plot the difference "spread".

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider using `dput()` to share a sample of your data and share code that you've written to try to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Please include sample data, the code you've tried so far, and your expected output. You can find guidelines for creating a good question at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it's a simple case of subsetting. if `dataset1` is the first dataset with 8 column and five rows, you can simply subset using:
`dataset2 <- dataset1[c(1,2),]` where 1 and 2 are the lines to keep. Since data is not in the dataset, you can build graph using date vectors as X and data from dataset2 for y.

I made an example:

```
df <- data.frame (a=c(2,4,6,8,9),
              b=c(1,5,7,9,10),
              c=c(6,8,5,7,7),
              d=c(1,2,3,4,5),
              e=c(4,5,6,2,1),
              f=c(2,5,4,7,1),
              g=c(1,1,2,1,2),
              h=c(5,6,5,5,5))
Vmin <- unlist(lapply(df, min))
Vmax <- unlist(lapply(df, max))
spread <- Vmax-Vmin
plot(spread, type = "o",pch=20, xaxt="n")
axis(1,1:8,colnames(df)) #or your date
```

[image]

Comment: What i want help with is that with observations High.price and Low.price for fives days, i want to plot the difference inbetween High.price and Low.price.

Comment: Sorry for misleading, what i want to do, is that i want to calculate the difference between the high.price and low.price for each day from the 5 observations which is dates. And from there i want to plot a geom_line with the 5 differences. Thanks alot